# Bamboo CI build script for different store apk

Tags: android, bash, build, apk, bamboo

So, i have an android app which uses different endpoints for each store (play store, amazon store).

I'm trying to create a build script in bamboo to be able to build it for "x" store. I want to give it as a variable in custom run build option in bamboo.

Right now i'm building it locally and I have a .properties file where i have a flag for store. (file is "MyProperties.properties" which contains: "AMAZON_BUILD = false" to be as playstore build)

How I should handle this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a properties file, I would pass the property via the build command line

```
ant -DAMAZON_BUILD=false
```

I would also output the apk to a store specific folder which would make it easier to pickup as an artifact.

Then run the build once for each store

Comment: avvi, I'm trying to setup Bamboo build system for Android Gradle project. I added **chmod +x gradlew** in Bamboo setup script file and that generate build successful but no apk there. Am I missing any other parameter to generate apk, Any suggestion here !!

Comment: Sorry I don't know what might be missing, I'm not familiar with gradle builds. Suggest you post a question. Make sure you include build output and command line. Good luck. @Shubh